# SAS enclosure doesn't restart - MSA60

Tags: storage, hp, hp-proliant, sas, hp-smart-array

I just inherited a HP StorageWorks MSA60 (this is a direct-attach SAS enclosure).
I had to move it to another shelf so I turned off the computer which was using it. I also pulled the 2 power cords off the MSA60 (no power button, so the only option was to disconnect from main power).

Once the device was in its new rack, I plugged the 2 power cords in and... nothing.
The fans are okay (I hear them). If I push the UID button, the corresponding light is okay. But the disks's LEDs stay off, and the disks stay off.

No power button on this device. So how to turn it on ?

Comment: By the way the MSA 60 is a SAS attached enclosure, not FC.

Comment: You should probably not be touching storage gear if you don't know the difference between FC and SAS, nor find a power button with the standard logo that happens to be on the back of the unit where all the other configuration buttons are as well. I don't mean to be offensive, please don't take it that way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Storageworks MSA60 enclosure has a "soft" power button. It does not power on automatically. When the power cables are connected, the unit defaults to a standby state.

Here's the rear of the [HP StorageWorks MSA60 enclosure](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12627_div/12627_div.HTML)...

[image]

On the right side of the rear of the unit, there's a module next to the right power supply which has a soft power button in the upper-right of the module, using the [universal standby signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_symbol).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many thanks ! I'm confused, it is not in my habits to miss something some evident. I checked 2 times without seeing it. I had to press the button for 2 or 3 seconds and tadaaa...

Comment: So, after a power-outage you have to go and turn it on by hand? Seems like a bit of a design flaw... Does it have a config option to power up when it receives A/C?

Comment: Single Domain?! The horror!

Comment: @MarkHenderson HP HBAs and MSA units will auto wake other MSA drive shelfs. It tends to get people who think the shelf has to be turned on first or who are using a configuration that hasn't been blessed by HP. The MSA70 and MSA2300 shelves work the same way.

Comment: I assumed as much if the shelf was slaved to a SAN unit. I didn't know that a P800 or P810 could wake the shelf, though...

Answer (score -2):

My experience with a power outage, is that the MSA60 *will* power back up just fine.

Comment: Did you read the other answer and comments? The MSA60 will power on when connected to certain HP devices. Otherwise, it doesn't. How does your answer improve on the quality of the answer?