# What does a RAID controller do if its conection to a SAS expander is severed?

Tags: raid, sas

When you have a RAID controller managing an array over a large amount of disks in an external chassis with a SAS expander, what happens if someone accidentally powers off the external chassis or accidentally unplugs the cable?  What's the worst and most likely cases in terms of data integrity in the array?

Comment: Things break badly and people are upset at you and perhaps loss of sleep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's why SFF-8088 external SAS cables have [locking connectors](http://www.dlbilder.de/produkte/orig/84db47087d8f8a009fee5f2decdffccc.jpg)... That's also why external JBOD power switches are [purposely hard to reach](https://serverfault.com/questions/365339/sas-enclosure-doesnt-restart-msa60/365349#365349) and typically require a long press to engage.

Given that, you're asking the same question as, *"What would happen if I pulled a group of disks out of a running system?"*

The answer is probably data loss, frustration and downtime... Don't let it happen.

- *Note, expanders are usually in the backplanes of external JBOD enclosures.*