# logical drives on HP Smart Array P800 not recognized after rebooting

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, raid5, hp-smart-array

We had a Smart Array P800 configuration working fine (RAID5). Physically, we have a disk enclosure (like [this](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/disk-enclosures/product-detail.html?oid=4021628#!tab=oas)) connected with a Linux Server. Here is what happened:

1. This server was accidentally rebooted.
2. The hpacucli utility (command line) run on the server immediately rebooted gave some strange disk failures and the logical drive was on a "failed" status.
3. We rebooted the disk enclosure and again the Server. We got this during rebooting

   `Drive positions appear to have changed.
   Run Array Diagnostics Utility (ADU) if previous positions are unknown.`
4. The hpacucli sees now all the disks as OK, but it lists them as "unassigned".

How can we re-create the logical drive with any loss of data? Is there some utility/command we can run to sort this out?.

Comment: Do you have the details of what you saw in `hpacucli`?

Comment: Yes: this is the result of `hpacucli ctrl all show status`: Smart Array P400 in Slot 1
   Controller Status: OK
   Cache Status: OK

Smart Array P800 in Slot 8
   Controller Status: OK
   Cache Status: Not Configured
   Battery/Capacitor Status: Failed (Replace Batteries/Capacitors)

Comment: If you mean at point 2.) of my description: No, I only remember that there were two discs with failure warnings. That is why we decided to reboot the enclosure.

Comment: if I try to mount from the location where it was before the logical drive `mount /dev/cciss/c0d0p2 /mnt/tmp/`, I get this: mount: you must specify the filesystem type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No, I only remember that there were two discs with failure warnings. That is why we decided to reboot the enclosure.

That was the wrong action to take. RAID5 and two failed disks is a dangerous combination. [RAID5 can only sustain a single disk failure](https://serverfault.com/a/339214/13325).

Your external enclosure is likely an [HP StorageWorks MSA60](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12627_na/12627_na.pdf), rather than the D2600 unit you linked. The main point is the same, though. You should have corrected the disk failures rather than reboot the enclosure/system. Having a logical drive in *failed* status means that the array has failed and the data is  possibly gone.

My recommendation to you is to power the server down and also physically remove power to the MSA60 enclosure (*remove the cables, don't just press the [power button](https://serverfault.com/questions/365339/sas-enclosure-doesnt-restart-msa60/365349#365349)*). Leave the systems off for 5-10 minutes.

Power the enclosure back on. Give it 60-90 seconds to spin up the disks. Follow by powering on the server.

Pay close attention to the POST messages, specifically the initialization of the Smart Array P800 controller. You MAY be prompted to *enable* a previously failed logical drive.

```
Logical drive(s) disabled due to possible data loss.
Select "F1" to continue with logical drive(s) disabled
Select "F2" to accept data loss and to re-enable logical drive(s)
RESUME = "F1" OR "F2" KEY
```

If prompted with this, you will want to press `F2` to re-enable the logical drive.

See what happens once the system has completed booting. If this is successful, you'll want to make sure the disks are healthy, then possibly update firmware on the server, controllers, disks and MSA units, since there have been bugs that trigger false drive failures and other undesirable behavior on this equipment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The POST message is the following: "An invalid drive movement was reported during POST. Modifications to the array configuration will result in loss of old configuration information and contents of the original logical drives." Do you know if it is possible to re-create the logical dirve?

Comment: @Bn_am Did you physically move any of the drives? You also have a failed RAID battery. Lots of bad news here.

Comment: No, we did not move any of the drives. Do you think that a failed battery can give to the controller the signal of an "invalid drive movement"?

Comment: We are thinking that some of the disk that now are OK were failed, then they went OK, and therefore the controller reports that we have moved something. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: @Bn_am If you allowed the server to reboot and bypassed the RAID controller prompts at boot that asked about the array, then yes, you may have lost your data. In either case, rebooting the enclosure with two failed drives in a RAID5 array was a dangerous and bad action. Right now, are all of the drives showing healthy?

Comment: The situation has changed, and we have now a logical drive disables as your examples. We either select F1 or F2 and we don't know. We you say "You should have corrected the disk failures rather than reboot the enclosure/system" what do you mean?

Comment: @Bn_am I mean that you should not have rebooted the system because you had failed disks. If you are being presented with the `F1` or `F2` option, please choose `F2`.

Comment: Choosing F2 will be better than trying to replace the failed disks with new ones? I mean, if there is any hope not to lose all the data..

Comment: @Bn_am Yes. Choose `F2`.

Comment: That seems to work. The data are there. Thank you very much

Comment: @Bn_am I'm glad you were able to recover your data. You may want to fix the bad battery and update system firmware when you have an opportunity.